# Can both substitution and transposition ciphers be thought of as permutations?

Tags: permutation

I came across this problem to 'explain why both substitution and transposition ciphers can be thought of as permutations' and I cannot come up with an explanation to how substitution ciphers can be thought of as permutations. Can somebody provide an explanation to this? It would really help me get a better understanding.

Edit:
This question is from the book `Cryptography and Network Security` by `Behrouz Forouzan`.

Comment: Oh sweet. They have really good explanations. Thanks a lot.